# Is $a$ in $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ always the semi-major axis?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In the equation for an ellipse:
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$
is $a$ always the semi-major axis of the ellipse, even if it is less than $b$? My inference is that it isn't, but $a$ seems to be used somewhat frequently in formulae to denote the semi-major axis specifically.

Comment: See here https://www.mathwarehouse.com/ellipse/equation-of-ellipse.php Hope it will clear all your doubts.

Comment: You can always rotate the axes, so that the major axis of the ellipse coincides with the (rotated) x-axis, so WLOG you can assume $a >= b$. That's what underlies the usaul convention.

Comment: As others said, there is no obligation. Often $a$ is taken as the semi-major axis because it is a widespread convention, so it is easier to get into a problem. Also, I noted that more people tend to draw ellipses with the major axis horizontally rather than vertically when asked to draw one without further constraints.